# gulp - loading subdirectory by default (example.com/en/)

Tags: gulp

I'm using the [Start Bootstrap SB Admin 2](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2) theme to build the UX of a multi-lingual site. Both languages will not be exactly the same, so each has its own design, and therefore different pages. Both, however, will use the same assets, CSS, and JS files.

I put all of my HTML files (depending on language) in two subfolders under a single folder in the root:

```
(root)
|_ css
|_ js
|_ locales
    |_ en
        |_ index.html
    |_ de
        |_ index.html
```

From my limited understanding of gulp, the solution lies in the `browserSync` function in my `gulpfile.js` file. The `browserSync` function looks like this:

```
...
// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    },
    port: 3000
  });
  done();
}
...
```

Of course, this does not load a page (`Can't GET /`) because `index.html` is not in the root folder `./`.

---

**What I would like** is for gulp to load `example.com/en/` (or `localhost:3000/en/`) by default so I can then access other directories inside the `locales` folder, such as `de` or any additional languages.

**Here's what I tried (1st attempt)**

```
// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./locales/en/"
    },
    port: 3000
  });
  done();
}
```

This loads the English index file, but any attempt to access the `de` directory wouldn't work, because the root URL is now inside the the `en` folder.

**Here's what I tried (2nd attempt)**

```
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    },
    index: '/pages/en/index.html',
    port: 3000
  });
  done();
}
```

I expected this to work, but what happened was exactly the same: `localhost:3000` would load the English index file, and attempting to access `localhost:3000/de` didn't work.

How can I set up gulp to load `/en/` by default, such that I can then access additional languages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./locales/"
      index: './locales/en/index.html',
    },
    port: 3000
  });
  done();
}
```